# Attempted import error:' is not exported from

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class, react-typescript

i cant resolve my problem. I have a file where I declare a class with the following code in lama.d.ts

```
export declare class lama  {


    // code here
}
```

Then I import this in another file in the same folder of my react project

```
import { lama} from './lama.d';
```

But I have the following error : Attempted import error: 'lama' is not exported from './lama.d'.

It does the same in a .ts instead of .d.ts file. And the mostt weird is that if I export another class from this file (lama.d.ts) that I import from another file to lama.d.ts , it works , but not the class that i wantt to work.

thank you for reading me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but used export default and it worked!

```
    declare class lama {
      // code here .. 
      export default lama
    }
```

**When import :**

```
    import lama from './lama.d'
```

Comment: thank you, but i finally just writed  "class lama" without declare and it worked

Comment: great, usually declare is used to tell TypeScript that the variable has been created elsewhere. If you use declare, nothing is added to the JavaScript that is generated - it is simply a hint to the compiler.